# why all vilidation sample outputs a same output

Tags: python, validation, keras, lstm

I train a mobile_net_v2 + LSTM neuron network for binary classification, the architecture as followed. 
The train data and validation data has the same distrubution of (1950,1140), when I apply the dropout layer of 0.5, the train data accuracy will be 100% in two epochs, but the validation accuracy is always in the 63.11, which means all the validation samples are classified as label0.

and if I remove the dropout layers, both of trian acc and val acc are about 63.11.

it's quit confusing for me.

## envs

the code is run in 16.04.1 Ubuntu, python 3.5.6, keras 2.2.4 with tensorflow-gpu 1.10.0 as backend .

## what I have done

I download the prediction of val sample, and all of them are same like [0.5024321,0.49...]
and I make the validation samples as train samples, and train samples as validation samples, it's still the same.
and another thing confuses me is that, I apply precision and reacall code like the followed for evaluating , they are same with val_acc.

## evaluate metrics

```
def recall(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    return recall   
def precision(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision
```

## model architecture

```
import yield_generator_v2

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0,1,2,3"  #CPU = -1

batch_size = 16
epochs = 5
seq_num = 25
input_shape =(seq_num,224,224,3)
lr = 1e-04

###model
mob = MobileNetV2(input_shape = (224,224,3), alpha = 1.0, include_top=False, weights = 'imagenet',pooling='avg')

model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(mob, input_shape = input_shape))
model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'))

model_multi_gpu = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus = 4)
adam = Adam(lr = lr)
model_multi_gpu.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='acc', patience=10, verbose=0, restore_best_weights=True)]


X = np.load('./X_tr_shuffled.npy')
y = np.load('./y_tr_shuffled.npy')

X_val = np.load('./X_val_shuffled.npy')
y_val = np.load('./y_val_shuffled.npy')

get_data = yield_generator_v2.generator(X, y, batch_size)
get_val = yield_generator_v2.generator(X_val, y_val, batch_size)
model_multi_gpu.fit_generator(generator = get_data, steps_per_epoch = 194, epochs = epochs, verbose = 1, validation_data = get_val, validation_steps = 194, callbacks = callbacks)
```

## yield_generator_v2

```
def generator (data, label, batch_size) :
    indices = np.ceil(len(data) / float(batch_size)).astype(int)
    while True:
        for idx in range(0,indices):
            batch_y = label[idx * batch_size : (idx+1) * batch_size]
            batch_x = data[idx * batch_size : (idx+1) * batch_size]
            batch_seq  = []  #batch_seq
            for x in batch_x:  #len(x) =16
                seq_img = []
                for img in x: #len(item) =25
                    seq_img.append(image.img_to_array(plt.imread(img)))
                seq_x = np.array([seq_img])
                batch_seq.append(seq_img)
            batch_seq_list = np.array(batch_seq)
            yield batch_seq_list, np.array(batch_y)
```

I expected it can work.

Comment: model is overfitting the training set. You can try a stratified sampling of the input data and check the model performance.

Comment: @venkata krishnan thx for your answer, but I think there's nothing about overfitting,  because of applying or removing the drropout layer lead to totally different results, overfitting can't make it sense